# Why Kivy apk crashes just after starting apk on android device

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer, kivymd

I m testing my incomplete kivy app to grap a suitable apk of that. using buildozer and ubuntu i generate the apk, but it crashes right after starting it on android device. Is buildozer spec file the root cause should change something inside that? , or its incompatible version issue.
please share kivy, kivymd, python and buildozer versions that are compatible. the py file is run on pycharm suitable with no error.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: I draw the logcat, here the issue supposedly " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'", However I have added kivymd to buildozer .spec file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `kivy 2.0.0rc4`. Install it in plugins trough settings in pycharm. And your `buildozer.spec` should be like this:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the requirements specidied in buildozer.spec file for the KivyMD-kitchen_sink app in the repo.

This is the link -> [Kitchen_Sink_Repo](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/buildozer.spec)

**Tip**

If, after changing the `requirements` you still see your app crashing, run the following command(s)

```
buildozer android clean
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Why?

Because when buildozer installs the earlier specified requirements, it is quiet possible that it installs versions that are not matching your apps specifications. So clean it and then run.

You should now be good to go.